# create upstart job exactly same in systemD ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upstart, systemd

we are running upstart job on ubuntu 14.04 for so many years, now we are about to move on to the new version of ubuntu as 16.04, But I am unable to create the same job in systemD.

```
description  "evercam_media"
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
limit nofile 1000000 1000000

respawn
chdir /
setuid root
setgid root

env HOME=/home/root
env LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env LANGUAGE=en_US:en
env LS_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
env ERL_MAX_PORTS=10240
env ERL_MAX_ETS_TABLES=5000
env PORT=4000
env MIX_ENV=prod


exec watch -n1 '/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh'

post-stop exec sudo pkill beam
```

while seeing few other people's work I have tried so many things but It's not starting my application, any help will be much-appreciated thanks, Sorry for so less information am very new with this kind fo stuff.

Update:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runner for My Phoenix App
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/etc/build/
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/my_phoenix_app.env
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh
ExecStop=sudp pkill beam
User=root
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I knew you are going to ask that.. I have updated the q

Comment: Please help if you can.. I am have tried so many things. But it's not working, my whole yesterday destroyed due to this and today is also going to be.. I know there is something missing which I dont know so please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

Your service doesn't have a type.

> One of the basic things that should be specified within the `[Service]` section is the `Type=` of the service. This categorizes services by their process and daemonizing behavior. This is important because it tells systemd how to correctly manage the service and find out its state.
>
> The `Type= directive` can be one of the following:
>
> `simple`: The main process of the service is specified in the start line. This is the default if the `Type=` and `Busname=` directives are not set, but the `ExecStart=` is set. Any communication should be handled outside of the unit through a second unit of the appropriate type (like through a .socket unit if this unit must communicate using sockets).
>
> `forking`: This service type is used when the service forks a child process, exiting the parent process almost immediately. This tells systemd that the process is still running even though the parent exited.
>
> `oneshot`: This type indicates that the process will be short-lived and that systemd should wait for the process to exit before continuing on with other units. This is the default `Type=` and `ExecStart=` are not set. It is used for one-off tasks.
>
> `dbus`: This indicates that unit will take a name on the D-Bus bus. When this happens, systemd will continue to process the next unit.
>
> `notify`: This indicates that the service will issue a notification when it has finished starting up. The systemd process will wait for this to happen before proceeding to other units.
>
> `idle`: This indicates that the service will not be run until all jobs are dispatched.

From Digital Ocean's  [Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)